# How to store file paths in a cross platform way in a .json configuration file in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, directory, configuration, path, cross-platform

How to store file paths in a cross platform way in a `.json` configuration file in ASP.NET Core?

E.g. I have the entry in the configuration:

```
MyPath: "C:\\Foo\\Bar"
```

And the path works on Windows, but does not work on Linux. I am aware of the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`, but how could I use it in the `.json`? Or should I use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
                    // IWebHostEnvironment _webHost
                    // IConfiguration Configuration
                    var listOfPath = Configuration["my-path"].ToString()
                        .Split("\\", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    var uploadPath = Path.Combine(_webHost.WebRootPath );
                    foreach (var folders in listOfPath)
                    {
                        uploadPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, folders);
                    }
```

Comment: Why would you use the `toString()` method? The configuration is returned as `string` anyway.